# Simple Form - Multiple attributes in checkbox group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I have a `User` Model with the following attributes:

```
#  full_time                :boolean
#  part_time                :boolean
#  contract                 :boolean
```

I would like to create a simple form checkboxes group for these attributes. From what I've been able to understand, the simple form api is meant to map to `has_many` & `has_and_belongs_to_many` associations, as follows:

```
f.collection_check_boxes :role_ids, Role.all, :id, :name
```

Is there a way to handle updating multiple attributes on the given model within the form's API guidelines? Or is this an indication that should I be modeling the data in a different way?

Comment: I would guess that `full_time`, `part_time`, and `contract` are mutually exclusive. If so, this seems IMO like a poor way to model them.

Comment: @jvillian In this case, they are not mutually exclusive. A user can be available for all types, as opposed to being defined by only one.

Comment: i did similar sort of thing before. i will update solution when i find time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f.collection_check_boxes` is a generic method for generating multiple checkboxes with arbitrary name/value, for a **single** attribute. The sample you gave is mentioned in the docs as a last one for this method, probably because `f.association` is way better for association attributes.

```
<%= f.association :role, Role.all %>
```

In case of your attributes, I don't think `f.collection_check_boxes` is applicable. If the attributes aren't mutually exclusive, then I don't see anything wrong - stick with them and just give each one a checkbox of it's own.

```
<%= f.input :full_time %>
<%= f.input :part_time %>
<%= f.input :contract %>
```

`simple_form` will detect their type and generate a checkbox for each. Use `wrapper: false` option, if you want to get rid of wrapper divs and group them more tightly.

If they were mutually exlusive, then an integer column and [`enum`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.5/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) would be probably a better idea.